# GPS message when turning on phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, gps, geolocation

I have a Nexus 5 running android 6.0, I was updating som apps when the phone turned off for low battery level. When i switch it on again I had a dialog saying that GPS is not active (as ever) and apps can't access to position. I have 2 options:
Close
Activate GPS
I've never seen this message before,.but now I have it every time i turn on my phone and it's  pretty annoying